# Cargo error after installing with apt on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo

I installed cargo using apt but it turned out it has an old version so i removed it and installed it again via rustup tool, but it is giving me this error when trying to install bob-nvim.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(poly1305_vec.o):poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x50b5): more undefined references to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1' follow
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(poly1305_vec.o): in function `poly1305_combine':
          poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7457): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x74d2): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x754d): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x75c8): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x764f): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(poly1305_vec.o):poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x76be): more undefined references to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds' follow
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(poly1305_vec.o): in function `poly1305_combine':
          poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x779d): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x77e1): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7809): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x785d): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7893): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x78d4): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7916): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7962): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x79c8): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7a0c): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7a35): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7a98): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7ace): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7b0f): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7b51): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7bb7): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7bfb): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7c24): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7c87): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.poly1305_combine+0x7cbd): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(poly1305_vec.o): in function `shr128_pair':
          poly1305_vec.c:(.text.shr128_pair+0x4c): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: poly1305_vec.c:(.text.shr128_pair+0xa5): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(poly1305_vec.o): in function `shr128':
          poly1305_vec.c:(.text.shr128+0x78): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(poly1305_vec.o): in function `GFp_memset':
          poly1305_vec.c:(.text.GFp_memset+0x53): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_nonnull_arg'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(montgomery_inv.o): in function `GFp_bn_neg_inv_mod_r_u64':
          montgomery_inv.c:(.text.GFp_bn_neg_inv_mod_r_u64+0x7b): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: montgomery_inv.c:(.text.GFp_bn_neg_inv_mod_r_u64+0xcb): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libring-edca6aa256ed13f7.rlib(ecp_nistz.o): in function `gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar':
          ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x63): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_divrem_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0xd4): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x104): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x18a): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x1a8): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x1d8): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x263): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x287): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x2c3): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x357): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x37b): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x3b7): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x44f): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x473): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x4af): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x54b): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x56f): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x5ab): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x63f): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x663): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x69f): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x733): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x757): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x793): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x827): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x84b): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x8f7): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow'
          /usr/bin/ld: ecp_nistz.c:(.text.gfp_little_endian_bytes_from_scalar+0x91b): undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `bob-nvim` (bin "bob") due to previous error

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name bob --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=131 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="rustls-tls"' -C metadata=f0828e72db20f3f0 -C extra-filename=-f0828e72db20f3f0 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps --extern anyhow=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libanyhow-ffbf2e450592b8c9.rlib --extern async_recursion=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libasync_recursion-53b3298da1c32f24.so --extern cfg_if=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libcfg_if-906f0c03e71b68f1.rlib --extern chrono=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libchrono-84d820959c008ff7.rlib --extern clap=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libclap-19cbc65b8b57a34c.rlib --extern clap_complete=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libclap_complete-1dcb8fe7b2a44893.rlib --extern dialoguer=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libdialoguer-e4ae00cccb8d0038.rlib --extern futures_util=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libfutures_util-bf949cb59d96be94.rlib --extern indicatif=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libindicatif-5e9150dd9b963b36.rlib --extern rand=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/librand-dbd1e69ae34b9c9e.rlib --extern regex=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libregex-1b765f761986a657.rlib --extern reqwest=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libreqwest-c3626a96c3d3c073.rlib --extern serde=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libserde-4cf32ea01616831c.rlib --extern serde_json=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libserde_json-a9a0a7db41bfc20b.rlib --extern tokio=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libtokio-5328705c1739596f.rlib --extern tracing=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libtracing-88ec72a83c4f077d.rlib --extern tracing_subscriber=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libtracing_subscriber-41fb1551d81b433b.rlib --extern yansi=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/deps/libyansi-612fd436da18b650.rlib -L native=/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj/release/build/ring-e887915416428d12/out` (exit status: 1)
error: failed to compile `bob-nvim v2.6.0 (https://github.com/MordechaiHadad/bob.git#cc5aaf14)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installMKuBVj`.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path.
```

any idea what might be causing this, i installed it via rustup tool on other machine and it works fine, but on my main machine it's still giving this error.

Comment: Did you run `cargo clean` in between switching from system to rustup toolchains? [This issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/compiler-builtins/issues/201) might be related but is closed.